# Are there any difference between "where : class, new()" and "where : new()"?

Tags: c#, generics

In C# while writing a generic class or function, are there any difference between `where : class, new()` and `where : new()`? Does `new()` imply that it is also `class`?

As I understand from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) structs cannot have parameterless constructors

Comment: Addressing your edit, they cannot have *explicit* parameterless constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does `new()` imply that it is also `class`?

No, `new()` just means the type has a public default constructor. Both classes and structs can have such constructors. Neither constraint implies the other in any way.

> As I understand from this structs cannot have parameterless constructors

The keyword in that document is "explicit", i.e. a constructor that you declare in code. A default constructor is an *implicit* parameterless constructor that's created by the compiler for a type when it has no explicit constructor definitions, with or without parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The `new()` constraint on a generic class or method means that `T` must have a default constructor but doesn't care whether `T` is a `class` or `struct`

Comment: It says here that structs cannot have parameterless constructors. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Nuri Tasdemir: The keyword there is "explicit." A default constructor is *implicit*.